# Помогите с DDNS IP камеры

Tags: ip, ddns, камера

Есть IP камера D-LINK - подключеная к сети. Сеть имеет доступ в интернет через роутер. На камере настроен DDNS и в сети ее видно через DDNS. А из другой интернет-сети - нет. Как решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша камера оказалась в `Intranet-сети` отделённая роутером (ещё и вероятно с `NAT`) от `Internet`.

Причина: `DDNS` привязывает адрес локальной сети к имени, поэтому из локальной сети её видно а из вне нет.

Решение: `DDNS` надо настраивать на роутере; и делать *"проброс портов"* для `IP` адреса вашей камеры (т.е. привязать камеру к "белому" `IP`-адресу - видимому из вне).

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте тут: как подключить IP камеру, чтобы она светила в инет? - разбор подобной проблемы.